# Duplicate a record but needs to increment one of the data fields

Tags: microsoft-access

I'm a newbie in ms access and i need someone to help me how to duplicate a record, but one of the fields should increment (+1).. thanks

Database is already been populated, one of the field is autonumber and that is not the one i need to increment, rest of the field has a short text data type. I had created a form and Im trying to add a text box or anything that will add "ANY QUANTITY IN THE TEXTBOX" in series of the previous copied data.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. There is no way anyone can give you a good answer because you haven't given enough details. Please read ***[ask]***, then edit your question to include more information. For instance, are you working in a table, form, query, etc? What version of Access are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: The idea of incrementing a text field is illogical. The expression "Vio"+1 is not a valid mathematical expression (in a finite universe at least). Most high level programming languages (including VBA which is what Access uses) will treat this as a string concatenation operation and return "Vio1". If you treat each character as a digit in base 26, then it would return "Vip". In short, your problem is that you haven't used the correct data type for your fields in the first place. http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/articles/software/access-data-types

Answer (score 1):

In Microsoft Access 2013, when you create a blank database, create a table. The first field in that blank table will be called ID. The Data Type is AutoNumber. AutoNumber means the field starts with a value of 1 and adds +1 each time you create a new record.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks sunk818.. im using ms accesss 2013.. the thing is there's already created tables with ID as autonumbered but that is not what i want to increment. Data is already been populated and the rest of the field are short text. One of them i need to increment in the form. I had created a button to duplicate but it should increment that one particullar field.

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify what you want to do. Explain if there is a starting number you want to start from if it is not one. If you add a field, what numbers do you want in the new field?